# how to set rules in mod_security module in Apache

Tags: apache, logging, httpd.conf, rules, apache-modules

Can someone please help me with setting rules such that i get only the data which is being posted using POST. I have a form where i am submitting name and email id. I want to save just that part to be saved in the log file. In my scenario i just want below data in my log file:-

```
--29000000-C--
name1=ssn&email1=ssn%40gmail.com
--29000000-F--
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.2.4
Content-Length: 16
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

My present mod_security looks like:-

```
<IfModule security2_module>
#Enable the module.
SecRuleEngine On
SecAuditEngine on

#Setup logging in a dedicated file.
SecAuditLog C:/wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.33/logs/website-audit.log

#Allow it to access requests body.
SecRequestBodyAccess on
SecAuditLogParts ABIFHZ

#Setup default action.
SecDefaultAction "nolog,noauditlog,allow,phase:2"

#Define the rule that will log the content of POST requests.
SecRule REQUEST_METHOD "^POST$" "chain,allow,phase:2,id:123"
SecRule REQUEST_URI ".*" "auditlog"

</ifmodule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my question. We can set below field as per our requirement:-

SecAuditLogParts ABIFHZ

In my case i set the field as:-
SecAuditLogParts C

however it will display as:-

```html
--84670000-A--
[29/Aug/2018:14:49:58 +0200] W4aWdqHJuCcOQzTIgCiEqAAAAD8 127.0.0.1 60735 127.0.0.1 80
--84670000-C--
name1=red&email1=red%40yahoo.com
--84670000-Z--
```